# set zoom camera on galaxy ace

Tags: camera, zooming, galaxy

on my galaxy ace:

```
parameters.isSmoothZoomSupported () = false
parameters.isZoomSupported () = false
```

But in the app default camera setting the resolution to 640 x 480, you can do the zoom.

How can I get the same effect?

I tried to set `setPictureSize()` manually, but it did not work

```
List<Size> sl = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
parameters.setPictureSize(sl.get(sl.size()-1).width, sl.get(sl.size()-1).height);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```